# How to show date in correct fromat like 12/04/2014

Tags: php

I have date in this format 12042014 from my database .but i want to display in that format 12/04/2014 or 12-04-2014,i am trying but not get a suitable solution please help me.sir
thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple workaround:

```
$x = '12042014';
$d = substr($x, 0, 2);
$m = substr($x, 2, 2);
$y = substr($x, 4, 4);

echo $d.'/'.$m.'/'.$y;
```

or you can store it as a [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
$date = new DateTime($y.'-'.$m.'-'.$d);

echo $date->format('Y/d/m');
```

Comment: thank you sir for giving me solution for my question

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$date = '12042014';

$date_new_format = 'New format: ' . substr($date, 0, 2) . '/' . substr($date, 2, 2) . '/' . substr($date, 4, 4);

echo $date_new_format; // test it out

?>
```